# How to apply "%.02f" in Python format function?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, floating-point, formatting

I'm new to python, recently I have migrated to Python 3 and
I'm trying to get used to the `format()` function.

What I'm trying to do is to `print()` the temperature I create
in floating-points, like so:

```
temperature = [23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
print("Today's temperature is %.02f" % (temperature[0]))
```

Instead of using `%.02f`, I would like to know how
that could be written in the `format()` function instead 
of the `%` percentage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use `{:.02f}`

```
>>> temperature = [23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
>>> print("Today's temperature is %.02f" % (temperature[0]))
Today's temperature is 23.00
>>> print("Today's temperature is {:.02f}".format(temperature[0]))
Today's temperature is 23.00
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings). However do see [*Format Examples*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

> `'%03.2f'` can be translated to `'{:03.2f}'`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! That should do it!

Answer (score 2):

As of Python 3.6, you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for such formatting:

```
>>> temperature = [23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
>>> print(f'Temperature is: {temperature[0]:.2f}')
Temperature is: 23.00
```